Delect portions of a Phone Number from a field called PhoneNumber
I want to select portions of a Phone number from a field called PhoneNumber, the numbers come in like example

(343)765-58584
(343)765-6544
(343)765-6758
etc

The numbers have same pattern just like this. So I want to select three different portions from this number, namely: countryCode, AreaCode and the Number, even though the numbers do not contain the country code but I will like to add that as field just incase.
This what am expecting from the output.
The right output:



CountryCode
AreaCode
Number





343
767-58584




Several concerns here. First, add your DBMS. Next, phone numbers around the world look vastly different, and some differ between lan vs mobile. I don't think mobile numbers in china have area codes. What is the source of these numbers? How are you to know if someone fat-fingered a 10-digits US number vs an 11-digit foreign number? Are you assuming the country code based on length? You need to add more sample data and expected output of these data, including a variety of global values that you would expect to see. I hope you have a country column. If not, then this seems futile.

Please learn how to ask question here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

String functions are different for different dbms.  It is useless for you if someone provide a solution, but with the wrong dbms.

@Isolated These numbers are already in the DBMS and they follow the same pattern, same length

Do you have only US and Canadian phone numbers? You don't have any from Sweden, China, Mexico, Sao Tome, etc? Please edit the question with all possible countries you have, to include examples.

All you need to know is here, in the official documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

@Isolated As i said i did not input the data, the data is already in the database and they all have the same patten with no country code just as you see above. I just want to grab the area code which is the (343) and the rest of the number 765-58584 in number field, in this case the numbers do not contain country codes

The preferred practice here is to have the incoming data pre-filtered so it's formatted consistently. That makes the SQL much simpler.

Required reading: Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Phone Numbers

If all the numbers are in exactly the same format then the simplest might be SUBSTRING(Phone, 2, 3) and SUBSTRING(Phone, 6, 100)

Please try the following solution based on tokenization via SQL Server's XML and XQuery functionality.
Notable points:

CROSS APPLY is tokenizing PhoneNumber column as XML.
Using XPath predicate /root/r[1]..., etc. we are retrieving 1st,
2nd, and 3rd tokens as required parts of a phone number.

SQL
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, PhoneNumber VARCHAR(200));
INSERT @tbl VALUES
('(343)765-58584'),
('(343)765-6544'),
('(343)765-6758'), 
('+972(305)765-6758');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = ')';

SELECT t.*
    , c.value('(/root/r[1]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)') AS CountryCode
    , c.value('(/root/r[2]/text())[1]', 'CHAR(3)') AS AreaCode
    , c.value('(/root/r[3]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS PhoneNumber
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
    REPLACE(REPLACE(PhoneNumber,'(',@separator), @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
    ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c);

Output



ID
PhoneNumber
CountryCode
AreaCode
PhoneNumber




1
(343)765-58584
NULL
343
765-58584


2
(343)765-6544
NULL
343
765-6544


3
(343)765-6758
NULL
343
765-6758


4
+972(305)765-6758
+972
305
765-6758




I'm sure there is any number of ways this can be done. Here is a straightforward solution using CharIndex, which seems the most obvious (though it may or may not be the best).
No attempt at handling errors here ... depending on how consistent and uniform your data is you will have better or worse results.
DECLARE @Phones TABLE (Phone NVARCHAR(100))

DECLARE @Result TABLE (
    OriginalValue NVARCHAR(100),
    Idx INT,
    AreaCode NVARCHAR(100),
    Phone NVARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @Phones 
    VALUES 
    (N'(123)456-7890'),
    (N'(123)456-78901')

INSERT INTO @Result (
    OriginalValue,
    Idx)
SELECT 
    p.Phone, 
    CHARINDEX(')', p.Phone) AS Idx
FROM 
    @Phones p

UPDATE r
SET 
    r.AreaCode = SUBSTRING(OriginalValue, Idx-3, 3),
    r.Phone = SUBSTRING(OriginalValue, Idx+1, 100)
FROM @Result r
WHERE r.Idx > 0

SELECT * FROM @Result

Result is:



OriginalValue
Idx
AreaCode
Phone




(123)456-7890
5
123
456-7890


(123)456-78901
5
123
456-78901



You would of course remove the Idx column and Original Value column, and use the area and phone columns to populate your cleaned up data ...
I just noticed that what you are calling country code is the area code but anyhow I'm sure you can handle that part as needed.

Assuming the data is clean (formatted the same every time), you can just use the SUBSTRING function on your incoming value [phonenumber]:
SELECT 
 SUBSTRING([phonenumber], 2, 3) as AreaCode
,SUBSTRING([phonenumber], 5, 9) as Number 

Note that I used "9" in the Number field because your example has a value with an extra number in it, but if that was a typo on your part then you could change this to "8". Alternatively you could set the value higher if you want to capture an arbitrary amount of numbers at the end. Setting it to "100" will still only return the 8 characters if there are only 8 characters.
If the data is not actually clean, you can scrub it with the REPLACE and/or STUFF functions to remove unwanted values.

How about the CountryCode field, if you refer to the table in the question

If your incoming data does not currently have a country code, there is nothing to worry about. If they add a country code later you will have to account for it by adjusting the index in each substring, and by adding a new field in the same way: SUBSTRING([phonenumber],1,1) would grab the first character from the input.
